# Prevent Scrollviewer from stopping in the middle of an element

Tags: wpf, scroll, touch, scrollviewer

I'm developing a touch application that uses a `ScrollViewer` and a `StackPanel` to make a carousel of images. The images are added to the `stackpanel` and the user slides them using fingers.

The problem is that I'm having a visual problem, what I want is to prevent the `scrollviewer` from stopping in the middle of two images. Just like this:

[image]

The idea is: when the inertia is stopping, automatically scroll to the nearest image.

Thats my XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="crlGalleryPlayer1" Panel.ZIndex="303"  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"  
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" PanningMode="HorizontalOnly" 
            PanningDeceleration="0.01" PanningRatio="1" 
            ManipulationBoundaryFeedback="crlCarrusel_Viewer_ManipulationBoundaryFeedback" 
            IsManipulationEnabled="True" Width="1920" Height="1080" Margin="0,0,0,0" CanContentScroll="False" Visibility="Hidden">
       <StackPanel Name="pnlCarrusel_ViewerPlayer1" Visibility="Visible" 
             ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="False"  IsManipulationEnabled="True" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
             Orientation="Horizontal" Panel.ZIndex="303">
       </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I've tried to start from the `ManipulationCompleted` event of the `Scrollviewer` but it's not getting fired, only `ManipulationStarted`

Thank you all.

Comment: Have you considered presenting an image and animating that off screen, another on. Rather than a scrollviewer. That would be like common phone apps look.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I need that kind of interaction with the images